# Should I trust Grive2?

Tags: privacy, cloud-computing

I am trying to run Google Drive on LUbuntu 64 bit, but since there isn't an official version yet, I was thinking to follow [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html) tutorial.
Since it's not an official software from Google, I am concerned about them seeing, copying, sharing, etc. my data. Should I trust them by following that tutorial and syncing my files using this software?

Comment: @DanielRuf I'm looking at the source code right now, it's an oAuth type authentication using cURL to communicate via REST using the official API. Here's something a little alarming; The client secret for the app `bl4ufi89h-9MkFlypcI7R785`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not trust the application. The client secret `bl4ufi89h-9MkFlypcI7R785` is embedded directly into the application. If you allow this application to be trusted by your Google account, then any permissions you give the app will be inherently granted to anyone who decides to maliciously make use of the client secret together with the client ID. Furthermore, the client secret leak breaks a layer of protection designed to ensure the legitimacy of the communicating server.

[Click here](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2/blob/3b608329b9c66583a0f985c4a4393af5dafc293e/grive/src/main.cc#L49) to view the main source code file containing the client secret.

Comment: You mean  https://github.com/vitalif/grive2/blob/3b608329b9c66583a0f985c4a4393af5dafc293e/grive/src/main.cc#L48

Comment: @DanielRuf Edited my answer

Comment: At least it is not a secret and it is a constant in the sourcecode. You are right. A corresponding issue should be created on GitHub. I know that there needs to be a client secret and client ID to create an app, but these should never be given to other users and be different for every user. This means every user should register their own client ID for the Google REST API.

Comment: @JonathanGray Thanks to all of you! The sad thing is that I feel like Grive is pretty famous: there are many articles and pages that recommend it. I hope that my question will save others from trouble. Is there an alternative to Grive, that you suggest me and that it's "safe"? Should I open another question for this?

Comment: @FormlessCloud You can still use Grive and workaround this security flaw if you want to go through all of the trouble. You would need to download the source code of Grive and sign up as a developer (through Google) to create an app for use with the Google Drive REST API. You will receive an app ID and an app secret. Take this information and modify the file in the Grive source code that you downloaded (you can see exactly where and in which file in the link in my answer). Then compile the application from source and you should end up with an executable file that you can run. But it's not easy.

Comment: @FormlessCloud Unfortunately it seems as though Grive is no longer being maintained and most likely does not even work. I have no alternatives that I can offer you personally. Good luck though.

Comment: @JonathanGray I am sorry, by saying Grive I meant Grive2 which is still maintained! Okay I've downloaded the source from GitHub, can you just tell me how am I supposed to compile such a project? I have all these files and folders that you see here: https://github.com/vitalif/grive2/tree/3b608329b9c66583a0f985c4a4393af5dafc293e which GCC command do I have to use to compile once I will replace the app ID and the app secret that I will get from Google?

Comment: Did you try cmake / make? The commands are all in the readme file and also the dependencies are mentioned.

Comment: @DanielRuf Yes I did, but I get lots of errors. I followed the guide but it stops when I run `make -j4`... Have you tried too?

Comment: @JonathanGray hey guys I've found this other one https://github.com/odeke-em/drive which seems much better. I've checked how they use the ClientSecret and seems to be okay. What do you think about it? And how can you be sure that that's the only thing we need to care about for security concerns?